# Cannot return value from within for loop? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, firebase, mkmapview

I am struggling with a function which I have made to take the selected annotation (didSelect view:), check the coordinate against all annotation coordinates in the database, and return the uid of the matching annotation.

However, I think I am making a mistake with my for loop, as it is not returning the value for use in the didSelect function. The searchForEvent function is called in didSelect view:, and checks the lat and long of the selected annotation against the database.

Heres the code:

```
 func searchForEvent(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) -> String? {
    var eventCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var eventKey: String?
    var selectedEventKey = ""
    DataService.instance.REF_EVENTS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("1")
        if let eventSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for event in eventSnapshot {
                eventKey = event.key
                print("\(eventKey)")
                print("2")
                if event.childSnapshot(forPath: "coordinate").value != nil  {
                    if let eventDict = event.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        print("3")
                        //pull out value of key coordinate
                        let coordinateArray = eventDict["coordinate"] as! NSArray
                        print(coordinateArray)
                        eventCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinateArray[0] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: coordinateArray[1] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                        print(eventCoordinate)
                        if (eventCoordinate?.latitude, eventCoordinate?.longitude) == (latitude, longitude) {
                            selectedEventKey = eventKey!
                            print("\(selectedEventKey), correct event")
                        } else {
                            print("incorrect event")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    return selectedEventKey

//        if selectedEventKey != nil {
//            print("4")
//            print("\(selectedEventKey)")
//            return selectedEventKey
//        } else {
//            print("empty key")
//            return nil
//        }
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("selected")
    self.selectedAnnotation = view.annotation
    print(selectedAnnotation?.coordinate.latitude as Any)
    print(selectedAnnotation?.coordinate.longitude as Any)
    let lat = selectedAnnotation?.coordinate.latitude
    let lon = selectedAnnotation?.coordinate.longitude

    selectedAnnotationKey = searchForEvent(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)

    if selectedAnnotationKey == nil {
        print("no key")
    } else {
        print("found event final! \(selectedAnnotationKey)")
    }
}
```

The selectedAnnotationKey is always nil in the didSelect function :(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is the updated function, thank you Sh_Khan for your help with it. While it is printing the right value in the debug area, it continues looping through the "events" in the database and returns nil at the end after finishing.

```
func searchForEvent(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees , completion:@escaping(_ str:String?) -> Void ) {
    var eventCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var eventKey: String?
    var selectedEventKey = ""
    DataService.instance.REF_EVENTS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("1")
        if let eventSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for event in eventSnapshot {
                eventKey = event.key
                print("\(eventKey)")
                print("2")
                if event.childSnapshot(forPath: "coordinate").value != nil  {
                    if let eventDict = event.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        print("3")
                        //pull out value of key coordinate
                        let coordinateArray = eventDict["coordinate"] as! NSArray
                        print(coordinateArray)
                        eventCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinateArray[0] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: coordinateArray[1] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                        print(eventCoordinate)
                        if (eventCoordinate?.latitude, eventCoordinate?.longitude) == (latitude, longitude) {
                            selectedEventKey = eventKey!
                            print("\(selectedEventKey), correct event")
                            completion(selectedEventKey)
                        } else {
                            print("incorrect event")
                            completion(nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("selected")
    self.selectedAnnotation = view.annotation
    let lat = selectedAnnotation?.coordinate.latitude
    let lon = selectedAnnotation?.coordinate.longitude

    searchForEvent(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!) { (str) in
        self.selectedAnnotationKey = str
        print("here it is \(str)")

        print(self.selectedAnnotationKey)
    }
}
```

And the debug printout:

```
selected
1
Optional("31E2932B-A037-4BB1-B93E-7504B61AC4E7")
2
3
(
    "-36.84745654404946",
    "174.7760903030886"
)
Optional(__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -36.847456544049464, longitude: 174.77609030308864))
incorrect event
here it is nil
nil
Optional("71173419-7E08-415C-9236-B1C8495A6BA9")
2
3
(
    "-36.86687593953122",
    "174.7585811441448"
)
Optional(__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -36.866875939531219, longitude: 174.75858114414478))
```

Below it finds the correct event, both str and self.selectedAnnotationKey are correct, but then keeps going and overwrites it!!!

```
71173419-7E08-415C-9236-B1C8495A6BA9, correct event
here it is Optional("71173419-7E08-415C-9236-B1C8495A6BA9")
Optional("71173419-7E08-415C-9236-B1C8495A6BA9")
Optional("7AC6429E-74B6-4A4E-A638-53981ACBFFBA")
2
3
(
    "-36.2429468",
    "175.3981152"
)
Optional(__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -36.242946799999999, longitude: 175.39811520000001))
incorrect event
here it is nil
nil
```

Comment: The for loop is not a problem but the event handler is the issue. Your event handler will be called **after** `searchForEvent(latitude:longitude:)`. You need to re-design your `mapView(_:didSelect:)`.

Comment: @OOPer How would this new didSelect: look?

Comment: Many things depend on what you really want to do. What do you want to do when you get multiple events (of the right coordinate, of course)?

Comment: At this point, there will be no events of the same coordinate, all I need is the correct key out of the function to pass into the next view controller which will load all the details of the selected event.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what part of your comment is answering to my question. But Sh_Khan's answer may be very near to what you want. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a completion

```
 func searchForEvent(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees , completion:@escaping(_ str:String?) -> Void ) {
    var eventCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var eventKey: String?
    var selectedEventKey = ""
    DataService.instance.REF_EVENTS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("1")
        if let eventSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for event in eventSnapshot {
                eventKey = event.key
                print("\(eventKey)")
                print("2")
                if event.childSnapshot(forPath: "coordinate").value != nil  {
                    if let eventDict = event.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        print("3")
                        //pull out value of key coordinate
                        let coordinateArray = eventDict["coordinate"] as! NSArray
                        print(coordinateArray)
                        eventCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinateArray[0] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: coordinateArray[1] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                        print(eventCoordinate)
                        if (eventCoordinate?.latitude, eventCoordinate?.longitude) == (latitude, longitude) {
                            selectedEventKey = eventKey!
                            print("\(selectedEventKey), correct event")
                            completion(selectedEventKey)
                        } else {
                            print("incorrect event")
                            completion(nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
 }
```

//

To call

```
searchForEvent(//value1,//value2) { (str) in
  print(str)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, your version of the function works well, however, the function is progressing through the loop in a weird way, I will show the updated function and the debug printout.

Answer (score 1):

You need a completion handler for this